# How to solve an integrand that diverge?

Tags: convergence-divergence, integration

In the following Eq. 1, the integral diverges. However, it is part of my equation for the Expectation of rate and it should not diverge. I will really appreciate any help as I am stuck on this for over 4 days now.

$$\begin{align}
E = \int_r^\infty\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{-x}}{1+ \mathrm{e}^{b-cx}}dx \tag{1} \label{1}
\end{align} $$

In the following, I found I can solve it using the **My Take** below, but even that diverges.

---

**My Take:**

--> following the properly $(1+z)^{-1} =  \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{j-1}(z)^{j-1}$

$E = \int_r^\infty\mathrm{e}^{-x}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{j-1}(e^{b-cx})^{j-1}$

$E$ diverge even now.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Do you have some conditions on $b, c$?

Comment: Because $\exp(z)\gt 0$ for all $z,$ your integrand is strictly less than $e^{-x}$ and its integral *converges* provided $r \gt -\infty.$  There is no mathematical issue here.

Comment: $r, b,c$ are positive real numbers.

Comment: It doesn't matter what values those numbers have: *the integral converges.*

Comment: What makes you think that this integral diverges?

Comment: The integral converges for all positive $b,c,r$. However, the expansion you have converges only when $cr > b$ (it turns into an asymptotic expansion for $cr < b$). The expectation of your rate is safe. It just means when $cr < b$, you cannot use the expansion to estimate the integral. This is just like the expression $\frac1{1+x}$. It behaves nicely for all $x > 0$ but you cannot use the expansion $ \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-x)^k$ to estimate $\frac{1}{1+x}$ for $x > 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your "My Take" and continue, you will get

$E = \int_r^\infty e^{-x}[\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{k} e^{(b-cx)k}]\space dx$

$=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k e^{bk}\int_r^\infty e^{-(kc+1)x} dx$

$=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k e^{bk}}{kc+1} e^{-(kc+1)r}$.

It converges.